# Solve struggles to solve equation with variable constraint

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to find `{x,y}` set satisfying first order conditions with the constraint:

```
0<x<=y<1
```

Here is my code, which does not give anything.

```
Dbuy = 1 - (x/y) - x*Log[y/x];
Dwait = (x/y) - x;
revx = D[(Dbuy*x + Dwait*CCC*y), x]
revy = D[(Dbuy*x + Dwait*CCC*y), y]
revsln=Solve[{revx==0, revy==0},{x,y}]
```

When I use `FindRoot` function instead of `Solve` for a fixed value of `CCC` (between 0 and 1, for example 0.4), it gives me numerical values (0.322, 0.581) if I add

```
{{x,0.01}, {y,0.01}}
```

But I want some form of closed-form solution for

```
0<=CCC<=1
```

What do you guys think?

Comment: Well, do you have any reason to expect a closed-form solution exists at all?

Comment: I feel that the root for the constraint 0<=x<=y<=1 has a closed-form. Is there a way to check it? Or is there a way to add a constraint to "Solve" function? Or is there a way to find a closed-form approximation?

Comment: In 11.3 I get a "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve." message. Probably means the system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve, no? Even if I drop the floating `CCC` I get `Root` objects parametrized near to a value.

Comment: Thanks b3m2a1, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Until someone comes up with a method that yields an analytical solution, you can use `NArgMax`:

```
argmax[c_?NumericQ] := NArgMax[{Dbuy*x + Dwait*c*y, 
  0 <= c <= 1 , 0 <= x <= 1, 0 <= y <= 1, x <= y}, {x, y}]

ParametricPlot[Evaluate @ argmax[c], {c, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Arrowheads[{.05, .05, .05, .05}],
    PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Frame -> True,  
   FrameLabel -> {{Style["y(c)", 16], None}, {Style["x(c)", 16], None}}, 
   GridLines -> (List /@ argmax[1/2]), MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
   Mesh -> {{{0, Directive[PointSize[Large], Red]},
         {1/2,  Directive[PointSize[Large], Orange]} , 
         {1, Directive[PointSize[Large], Green]}}}, 
   PlotLegends -> PointLegend[{Red, Orange, Green}, {"c = 0" , "c = 1/2", "c = 1"}], 
   Prolog -> {Gray, Arrowheads[0], Thin, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]} ] /. 
 Line -> Arrow
```

[image]

Comment: are these the optimal (x,y) combinations for 0<=c<=1?

Comment: @Ovunc, yes they are.

Comment: This is very cool! Thank you. Is there any way to map at least a few $c$ values on this?

Comment: @Ovunc, please see the updated version.

Comment: Wow this is super cool! Thanks so much kglr!

Comment: I am working on a simple but interesting constrained optimization problem and your figure gave me some interesting ideas about how to present the results.

Comment: First original optimization function is m*(Dbuy*x + Dwait*c*y) where m*(Dbuy+Dwait)<=1. For some low values of m, the FOCs give the optimal results. After that, FOCs violate the constraint so x and y increase within the constraint (I assume revx=0 or revy=0 for that case). There is also a version of the same problem where m*Dbuy<=1 & m*(Dbuy+Dwait<=2).

Second optimization is m*(Dbuy*x + Dwait*c*y+Dlock*(z+c*y)) where m*(Dbuy+ Dwait+Dlock)<=1. Similar idea, but this time I have three decision variables: x, y, z. And this problem has another version where m*Dbuy<=1 & m*(Dbuy+ Dwait+Dlock)<=1.

Comment: @Ovunc, hope this post helps with one step of the problem.

Comment: This was amazing help. I will certainly use argmax after now. Do you have any suggestions for the cases when I have three variables?

Comment: @Ovunc, same approach should work using `ParametricPlot3D` (just remove `Epilog`) for three decision variables.

Comment: = Edit: Worked second time =

Comment: Thanks so much kglr!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84784/discussion-between-ovunc-and-kglr).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to get a sense for the kinds of things for want. We'll solve this (exactly!) for a large number of values for `CCC`, plot them, and extract meaning out of that.

Here's the basic code I'll fux with:

```
blurg[CCC_] :=
 Block[
  {
   ccc = Rationalize[CCC],
   Dbuy,
   Dwait,
   revx,
   revy,
   x, y
   },
  Dbuy = 1 - (x/y) - x*Log[y/x];
  Dwait = (x/y) - x;
  revx = D[(Dbuy*x + Dwait*ccc*y), x]; 
  revy = D[(Dbuy*x + Dwait*ccc*y), y];
  Solve[{revx == 0, revy == 0}, {x, y}, Reals]
  ]

solns =
  blurg /@ Rest@Subdivide[0, 1, 100];

N[{x, y} /. #, 50] & /@ solns // 
 ListPlot[#, PlotStyle -> Map[Hue, Range[0, 1, 1/Length@solns]]] &
```

[image]

You can see you always have two solutions and they converge down to those end-points at `CCC=1` and apparently diverge as `CCC->0`

You can also look at the symbolic solutions returned but they will be *nasty*. Lots of complicated `Root` objects

Here's another fun example:

```
solns =
  blurg /@ Rest@Subdivide[0, .01, 25];

N[{x, y} /. #, 50] & /@ solns // 
 ListPlot[#, PlotStyle -> Map[Hue, Range[0, 1, 1/Length@solns]]] &
```

[image]

This shows the divergence over that side of the solutions.

Comment: Interesting work. I ran your code and saw the optimal (x,y) sets, but only numbers. I also saw the two-solution issue, but it is not a problem because x>y in the second solution of each c-value.

Comment: I wonder if you can tell me a bit how this code works and how I can see the symbolic solutions.

Comment: @Ovunc all of the `solns` give you symbolic solutions. I just provided a series of exact values for `CCC` and told `Solve` to solve it over the real numbers (that might not be necessary but I didn't really care to change it). I then extracted them with `ReplaceAll` and numericized them with `N`.

Comment: What change should I make in the code to see the symbolic solutions? Are there more than two of them?

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward solution might be found using NMinimize with constraint `0 < x <= y < 1`:

```
sol[CCC_?NumericQ] := {x, y} /. 
NMinimize[{1, {1 + CCC + x - (2 x)/y - CCC y - 2 x Log[y/x] == 0, -((x (x (-1 + y) + CCC y^2))/y^2) == 0, 
  0 < x <= y < 1}}  (* constraint *)
, {x, y}][[2]]
```

Plot gives (after a while...)

```
Show[{ParametricPlot[ sol[c], {c, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red,PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, AxesLabel -> {x[c], y[c]}], 
RegionPlot[0 < x <= y < 1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]}]
```

[image]

the solution `{x[c],y[c]} , 0<c<1` (same solution @kglr gave)

Answer (score 0):

Although it may not be possible to obtain a symbolic solution for `{x, y}` as a function of `CCC`, it is straightforward to obtain a symbolic solution for `{x, y, CCC}` as a function of `x/y`.  The derivation proceeds as follows:

```
s = Solve[{revx == 0, revy == 0} /. y -> a x, {x, CCC}] // Simplify
(* {{x -> (4 - a + Sqrt[8 - 8 a + a^2 + 8 Log[a]])/(4 a - 4 a Log[a]), 
     CCC -> -((-2 + a + Sqrt[8 - 8 a + a^2 + 8 Log[a]])/(2 a))}, 
    {x -> (-4 + a + Sqrt[8 - 8 a + a^2 + 8 Log[a]])/(4 a (-1 + Log[a])), 
     CCC -> (2 - a + Sqrt[8 - 8 a + a^2 + 8 Log[a]])/(2 a)}} *)
```

To plot this result, it is convenient to obtain limits on `a` corresponding to those on `CCC`.

```
alim0 = Flatten[FindRoot[# == 0, {a, 1}] & /@ (CCC /. s)] // Values
(* {1., 3.51286} *)

alim1 = Chop[Flatten[Quiet@FindRoot[# == 1, {a, .8}] & /@ (CCC /. s)], 10^-7] 
    // Values
(* {0.692201, 1.} *)
```

The plot shown in earlier answers can be obtained by

```
Show[Plot[Null, {x, .25, 1}, PlotRange -> {Full, {.49, 1}}, ImageSize -> Large, 
        AxesLabel -> {x, y}, LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 12}], 
    ParametricPlot[{x, a x} /. First[s], {a, First@alim1, 1}], 
    ParametricPlot[{x, a x} /. Last[s], {a, 1, Last@alim0}]]
```

[image]

And, the `CCC` dependence is shown by.

```
Show[Plot3D[Null, {x, .25, 1}, {y, .5, 1}, PlotRange -> {Full, Full, {0, 1}}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {x, y, CCC}, LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 12}], 
    ParametricPlot3D[{x, a x, CCC} /. First[s], {a, First@alim1, 1}], 
    ParametricPlot3D[{x, a x, CCC} /. Last[s], {a, 1, Last@alim0}]]
```

[image]

Imposing the additional constraint given in the question, `0 < x <= y < 1` is achieved by using only the second solution, `Last[s]`, which appears at the left of the two plots.  The explicit dependence of `{x, y}` is, then,

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{{CCC, x}, {CCC, a x}} /. Last[s]], {a, 1, Last@alim0}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {CCC, "x, y"}, 
    LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 12}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

Addendum

In response to a comment by the OP, below, the maximum value of the objective function can be determined and marked on a plot of the objective function (here with `CCC == 0.1`) can be accomplished by

```
dta = (FindMaximum[{Dbuy*x + Dwait*0.1*y, x <= y, 0 < x < 1, 0 < y < 1}, {x, y}] 
    // Reverse // Flatten) /. Rule[_, z_] -> z
(* {0.286834, 0.785105, 0.105362} *)

Show[Plot3D[Dbuy*x + Dwait*0.1*y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
        RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x - y <= 0], 
        PlotRange -> {0, Automatic}, Mesh -> None, ImageSize -> Large, 
        AxesLabel -> {x, y, f}, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 12}], 
    ListPointPlot3D[{dta}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Medium}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, it feels like this graph is the right of two.

Comment: Can we show that the actual function is concave somehow?

Comment: To which function or functions are you referring?  There are several in your question and my answer.

Comment: The objective function, (Dbuy*x + Dwait * ccc * y), is not concave.

Comment: And thanks so much! I am working on your code right now!

Comment: Do you know a way if I can mark the maximal value on the Plot3D[Dbuy*x + Dwait*0.1*y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x - y <= 0]]

Comment: @Ovunc  Done.  By the way I corrected the third plot in the original answer.

Comment: Wow very good! Thanks bbgodfrey!